# Inserting row to multiple tables failed

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, sql-server-2005

i have one stored procedure that inserting row to multiple table same time. there is problem in stored procedures that it's not fired. can u just look at this syntax is it correct and working.

```
    set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InquiryPostReply]
(
    @Inquiry_id VARCHAR(50),
    @User_id VARCHAR(50),
    @Priority_type VARCHAR(25),
    @Status_name VARCHAR(50),
    @Inquiry_Content VARCHAR(1024),
    @Question_id NUMERIC(18,0),
    @user_name VARCHAR(50) OUT,
    @user_email VARCHAR(50) OUT,
    @NewId VARCHAR(50) OUT
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @var1 int
declare @var2 int
declare @uniqueRef char(14)
set @uniqueRef = dbo.UniqueRefNum(rand(), rand(), rand(), rand())
set @var1= (SELECT [Id] FROM [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Status_master] WHERE (Status_name=@Status_name))
set @var2= (SELECT [Id] FROM [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Priority_master] WHERE (Priority_name=@Priority_type))
set @user_email=(SELECT [Email_Address] FROM [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Inquiry_History] WHERE (Inquiry_id=@Inquiry_id))
set @user_name= (SELECT tbl_User_master.Full_Name FROM tbl_Inquiry_History INNER JOIN tbl_User_master ON tbl_Inquiry_History.User_id = tbl_User_master.Id WHERE(tbl_Inquiry_History.Inquiry_id=@Inquiry_id))
IF @var1 = '1'
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Inquiry_master]
           ([Id],[Inquiry_id],[User_id],[Priority_id],[Status_id],[body])
  VALUES
          (@uniqueRef,@Inquiry_id,@User_id,@var2,@var1,@Inquiry_Content)
  INSERT INTO [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Answer]
           ([Question_id],[body],[Created_date])
  VALUES
           (@Question_id,@Inquiry_Content,CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(), 101))
  UPDATE [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Inquiry_History] 
  SET [Priority_id] = @var2,[Status_id] = @var1,[IsDisplay] = 1,[IsReplied] = 1,[TimeStamp] = CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(), 101)
  WHERE (Inquiry_id=@Inquiry_id)
END
ELSE IF @var1 = '2'
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Inquiry_master]
           ([Id],[Inquiry_id],[User_id],[Priority_id],[Status_id],[body])
  VALUES
          (@uniqueRef,@Inquiry_id,@User_id,@var2,@var1,@Inquiry_Content)
  INSERT INTO [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Answer]
           ([Question_id],[body],[Created_date])
  VALUES
           (@Question_id,@Inquiry_Content,CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(), 101))
  UPDATE [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Inquiry_History] 
  SET [Priority_id] = @var2,[Status_id] = @var1,[IsDisplay] = 1,[IsReplied] = 1,[TimeStamp] = CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(), 101)
  WHERE (Inquiry_id=@Inquiry_id)
END
ELSE IF @var1 = '3'
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Inquiry_master]
    ([Id],[Inquiry_id],[User_id],[Priority_id],[Status_id],[body])
  VALUES
    (@uniqueRef,@Inquiry_id,@User_id,@var2,@var1,@Inquiry_Content)
  INSERT INTO [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Answer]
           ([Question_id],[body],[Created_date])
  VALUES
           (@Question_id,@Inquiry_Content,CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(), 101))
  UPDATE [OmStocks].[dbo].[tbl_Inquiry_History] 
  SET [Priority_id] = @var2,[Status_id] = @var1,[IsDisplay] = 0,[IsReplied] = 1,[TimeStamp] = CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(), 101),[Activity_expire_time] = CONVERT(DATETIME,GETDATE(), 101)
  WHERE (Inquiry_id=@Inquiry_id)
END
SET @NewId = @uniqueRef
END
```

how ever this stored procedure working fine while i'm execute from management studio from code behind it's execute successfully but doesn't inserting records to tables. there for i include this databasehelper.cs code:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Adds answer in the [tbl_Inquiry_master] table.
    /// </summary>
    public static void AddPostReply(string inquiry_id,string user_id,string priority_type, string status_name, string inquiry_content,int question_id,out string reply_id,out string user_name,out string user_email)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = Util.GetConnection())
        {
            con.Open();
            AddPostReply(con,inquiry_id,user_id,priority_type, status_name, inquiry_content, question_id,out reply_id,out user_name,out user_email);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds answer in the [tbl_Inquiry_master] table.
    /// </summary>
    public static void AddPostReply(SqlConnection con, string inquiry_id, string user_id, string priority_type, string status_name, string inquiry_content, int question_id, out string reply_id, out string user_name, out string user_email)
    {
        AddPostReply(con, null, inquiry_id, user_id, priority_type, status_name, inquiry_content, question_id, out reply_id, out user_name, out user_email);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds answer in the [tbl_Inquiry_master] table.
    /// </summary>
    public static void AddPostReply(SqlConnection con, SqlTransaction trans, string inquiry_id, string user_id, string priority_type, string status_name, string inquiry_content, int question_id, out string reply_id, out string user_name, out string user_email)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[InquiryPostReply]", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Inquiry_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = inquiry_id;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user_id;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Priority_type", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = priority_type;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = status_name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Inquiry_Content", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = inquiry_content;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Question_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = question_id;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NewId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
           if (trans != null)
            trans = con.BeginTransaction();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        trans.Commit();
            user_name = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@user_name"].Value);
            user_email = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@user_email"].Value);
            reply_id = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@NewId"].Value);
        }
    }
```

----------------------------------Updated------------------------------------------

the error occured like:

```
    Server Error in '/OmInvestmentStockMarketing_new' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 140:                trans = con.BeginTransaction();
Line 141:            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 142:            trans.Commit();
Line 143:            user_name = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@user_name"].Value);
Line 144:            user_email = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@user_email"].Value);

Source File: c:\Documents and Settings\Vishal\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\OmInvestmentStockMarketing_new\App_Code\DatabaseHelper.cs    Line: 142 

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   DatabaseHelper.AddPostReply(SqlConnection con, SqlTransaction trans, String inquiry_id, String user_id, String priority_type, String status_name, String inquiry_content, Int32 question_id, String& reply_id, String& user_name, String& user_email) in c:\Documents and Settings\Vishal\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\OmInvestmentStockMarketing_new\App_Code\DatabaseHelper.cs:142
   DatabaseHelper.AddPostReply(SqlConnection con, String inquiry_id, String user_id, String priority_type, String status_name, String inquiry_content, Int32 question_id, String& reply_id, String& user_name, String& user_email) in c:\Documents and Settings\Vishal\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\OmInvestmentStockMarketing_new\App_Code\DatabaseHelper.cs:120
   DatabaseHelper.AddPostReply(String inquiry_id, String user_id, String priority_type, String status_name, String inquiry_content, Int32 question_id, String& reply_id, String& user_name, String& user_email) in c:\Documents and Settings\Vishal\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\OmInvestmentStockMarketing_new\App_Code\DatabaseHelper.cs:112
   Admin_OWM_Inquiry_Post_Reply.btnsubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Documents and Settings\Vishal\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\OmInvestmentStockMarketing_new\Admin\OWM_Inquiry_Post_Reply.aspx.cs:51
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

please help me..

Comment: For the third time remove the transaction and test.  The error is on the trans.Commit() line.  First determine if the problem is in the SP.

Comment: Then most likely that trans is null.   You should also test for null on the line Commit line.

Comment: now it's works fine without transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the transaction on your connection, execute your statements, and then commit those changes.

```
trans = con.BeginTransaction();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
trans.Commit();
```

Comment: this code doesn't help me can u implement this code to my method.

Comment: The code you have implemented above based on my response should work. Your error you're receiving is bubbling up from SQL Server and means your data is committing but you have a conflict. You need to revise your SQL procedure.

Comment: ya ur code works fine but suddenly my page become blank. is that problem in my stored procedure.

Comment: I can't give you an answer because I have no idea what data you're inserting. Either your INSERT or UPDATE is failing because of a foreign key issue

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem to me

```
IF @var1 = '1' AND  @var1 = '2'
```

That will always return false

And you need to commit the transaction as indicted by dgarbacz

Comment: i update my stored procedure but this gives me error see updated section.

Comment: You STILL are not committing the transaction.  First try removing the transaction.

Comment: Not you did not take my suggestion.  I said first try removing the transaction.